# How to catch user even (click on a button) from windows UWP app while running WinAppDriver (Appium)

Tags: javascript, automation, appium, addeventlistener, winappdriver

I need to catch user even and perform some script after it  while driver is running

What I want to solve:

1. Run auto test on UWP app via WinAppDriver
2. Perform some steps
3. Wait for user input
4. If button clicked -> do script, else user continue using app

   ```
   import { driver, By2, windowsAppDriverCapabilities } from 'selenium-appium'    
   const capabilites = windowsAppDriverCapabilities(<WinAppId>);

   driver.startWithCapabilities(capabilites, 'http://localhost:4723/wd/hub');
   ...
   let someButton = driver.findElement(By2.nativeXpath("//*/ButtonPosition"))

   while (true){
     someButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      <somelogic>
     })
   ```

TypeError: test.addEventListener is not a function

● Test suite failed to run

WebDriverError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy command to the remote server. Original error: read ECONNRESET